# How can i get GPS current status in Appium

Tags: automated-testing, android, appium

I do some testing with appium with ad Android Application.
I want to know if i can get gps current status, if gps is in use in that instant or not. 
I don't want know if gps is enable or disable.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/843675/631619 although not appium

Comment: this is not help me much.